# htaccess for subdirectories to prevent script execution

Tags: php

I have sub directory 'images' with permission 777 to upload images from visitors
in this folder there is .htaccess file to prevent script execution and more security

```
<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.JPEG|*.JPG|*.png|*.gif)>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$">
ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

But when i request images/page.php in browser, it is working **which is meaning .htaccess does not working**.
I want to prevent this folder from executable file.

**Is there any mistake in my .htaccess file**

Comment: check http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess_for_subdirectories

Comment: yes NullPointer, my code from codex.wordpress.org/htaccess_for_subdirectories but does not work

Comment: You are aware that `ForceType text/plain` will allow anyone to download your PHP scripts' source code? Not a problem in your case, but be careful.

Answer (score 2):

One more comment here, I would advise to case insensitive check for your scripts rule, that would be:

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(php5|php4|php|php3|php2|phtml|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$">
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

This works fine for our server.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can access all .php files, because you are only forbidding access to the image files. I think there also should be a $ at the end of the first regular expression. Maybe you mean something like this:

```
<Files *>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>

<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.JPEG|*.JPG|*.png|*.gif)$>
    order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$">
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: thanx Adder, but php file still work in images folder,
may be .haccess inherit from root .htaccess. but how avoid it